# Windows form is associated with the wrong code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

When clicking 'View Code' on the form in Visual Studio 2013 I am shown only the automatically generated design code. Similarly, if I try to add a new event handler via the events section of a control's 'Properties' pane, then the code is automatically added to the designer code which is obviously not correct. Trying to add the event to the *actual* form code is fine, but it will not let me associate it with a control on the form. However, all previous event handlers remain active and correctly associated with the form and it's controls.

Strangely enough, there is another blank form present in the solution explorer that, when clicked, takes me to the *actual* form code mentioned above.

I suspect that this issue was caused when I copied the form code into the solution from another (the old solution messed up because stupid me didn't use version control) hence my association issues. If someone could explain how I can go about regaining the correct associations between the files again it would be much appreciated.

Extra information - the solution hierarchy shows two forms, one blank and one actual form. The real form code file is shown below both.

Comment: actually the behavior you describe regarding events *is* correct; if you add an event via the designer, it will (and should) add it to the designer file. I would check your class names and namespaces.

Comment: The namespaces and class names are correct; they were the first thing I checked. I also just made a new project to test what you said about events, and I don't believe that is true. On a clean project, adding an event via the designer added it straight into the form code. I appreciate your response nonetheless.

Comment: to be clear, the handler should be in the designer; you get a method to implement in your code file. Are you saying that it generates a method in the designer file?

Comment: My apologies, you are indeed correct in that I was trying to say that the actual method is generated in the designer file as opposed to just the event handler. I'm aware that I could implement my own event handlers in the code, but I felt that this was an opportunity to learn why this issue is occurring.

Comment: no worries. Check out the answer below and see if that helps you get back on track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would check is the project file; I suspect you've got some bad mapping between designer/code files in there. You'll need to right-click on the project and select `Unload Project`, then right-click it again and select `Edit XXX.csproj` (You can also open up that file in any other program, it's just an XML file). Look for the `<ItemGroup>` node that contains the `<Compile>` nodes; on a brand new winforms app it looks like this for the generated form:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>

...
```

Make sure that your designer files are dependent on the correct code files.